# Turf.js Check if polygon "Contains" another polygon

Tags: javascript, openlayers, turf

I am using turf.js for geometrical operation on openlayers3 features but i think it lacks support for "contains" operation.

There are these [within](http://turfjs.org/examples/turf-within/) and [inside](http://turfjs.org/examples/turf-inside/) operations, but they return "false" when i check it with the polygon. Is there any other way to do this "contains" operation with turf.js or do i have to use the JSTS?

Comment: JSTS is a better solution in my personal opinion. But in your case if a point is `within` a polygon then this polygon `contains ` your point.

Comment: Thanks @pavlos for reply, but my requirement is not to check the point within polygon, but polygon contains "polygon". And yeah may be looping through the coordinates of 2nd polygon and then checking the "within" to first polygon solves the problem, but that becomes an unnecessary task.

Comment: Turf `within` and `inside` checks for a set of points against a polygon. http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_within.html. So obviously wont  work for polygons to polygons. Though looping through polygon points (as you describe) shall give you the solution. Why do you think this is an unnecessary task? In your case seems to be neccessary ..... unless you want to use JSTS, which in my personal opinion is more elegant and complete library

Comment: I believe that its better to leave such tasks on libraries. That is the reason they made up for. Anyway, I have shifted to JSTS to achieve this. Also, hope turf.js soon implement the "contains" so we can have an answer with "turf.contains"

Comment: Much of Turf has relied on JSTS it turns out: https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/issues/88

Comment: Not really knowing anything about either of these prior to a few hours ago, I'd say turf is far better documented than JSTS. With JSTS all I could find was a link the the Java API and a site with about 4 examples. Am I missing something?

Comment: @redbmk same here, struggling to find out if JSTS will even do what I want.

Comment: @redbmk In case it helps I managed to track down the JSTS API here: http://bjornharrtell.github.io/jsts/doc/api/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be able to use the [turf/boolean-contains](http://turfjs.org/docs/#booleanContains) module, noting that this only returns a true or false answer. Hope that helps

Comment: Given that this question was asked in '15. And currently i am not working on the same, yet the description on at the URL shared seems like finally this support is added to turf.js. Hence accepting this as answer.